# Где ошибка в решении задачи на сложение чисел?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется задача на сложение трех чисел. Если одно из слагаемых равно 13, то последующие числа в сумме не учитываются. Правильное решение выглядит так:

```
public int luckySum(int a, int b, int c) {
  if (a == 13) {
    return 0;
  } if (b == 13) {
    return a;
  } if (c == 13) {
    return a + b;
  } else {
    return a + b + c; 
  }
}
```

В моем решении я пошел от переменной `int sum`:

```
public int luckySum(int a, int b, int c) {
  int sum;

  if (a == 13) {
    sum = 0;
  } if (b == 13) {
    sum = a;
  } if (c == 13) {
    sum = a + b;
  } else {
    sum = a + b + c;
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Получилось, что для чисел `(1, 2, 13)` данный вариант работает правильно, а для чисел `(1, 13, 2)` выдается полная сумма, `16`. С чем это может быть связано?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй тогда  else if
......

Comment: Да, благодарю, с if-else все заработало.